# Destructuring within object literal with alias

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am tying to construct an object literal with two keys coming from a function

```
const someFunc = () => {foo: "hi", bar: "bye" }
```

```
const x = {
   a: "hello",
   b: "world",
   ...someFunc()
}
```

I am trying to figure out a one liner where i can set the alias of `foo` and `bar` to `c` and `d`.

Help appreciated. I am using TS

Comment: Why does it need to fit on one line? TypeScript's going to render your code differently after transpilation anyway.

Comment: because this piece of code is in arrow function in a format `() => ({...some thing happing here..})`

Comment: ... which could easily be rewritten as `() => { /* do something over more than one line */ return { ... }; };` Aim for readability, not cleverness. My advice, freely ignorable. :)

Comment: `...(({ foo: c, bar: d }) =>({ c, d }))(someFunc())` - but please don't

Comment: Note that `someFunc()` as written is a syntax error; if you want to return an object literal you need to wrap it in parentheses.  Please try to make sure that code in questions constitutes a [mcve].  Good luck!